# Moving one row to bottom of a sheet after date has passed (updated)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I posted a few months ago about looking for a macro that can help move a row of a sheet to the bottom of it once it passes a certain date. Original post here: [Moving one row to bottom of a sheet after date has passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75342811/moving-one-row-to-bottom-of-a-sheet-after-date-has-passed)

I recently added two columns to this sheet and can't figure out how to update the script. Here's the updated sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EPueop9bdky_J8VgpFdSUzzsMRieRUreeCRIy18ScTY/edit#gid=0

I'm also copying the script I've already updated below:

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // or const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  const row = sheet.getRange("A4:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("Completed").findNext().getRow();
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  const moves = sheet.getRange("H4:H" + (row - 1)).getValues().reduce((ar, [f], i) => {
    if (f && f.getTime() < now) {
      const r = i + 4;
      ar.push(sheet.getRange(`A${r}:H${r}`));
    }
    return ar;
  }, []).reverse();
  const len = moves.length;
  if (len == 0) return;
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  moves.forEach((r, i) => sheet.moveRows(r, lastRow - i + len - 1));
}
```

Unfortunately, I keep receiving the following error:

**Error Exception: Those rows are out of bounds.**

**(anonymous) @ Code.gs:15**

**myFunction @ Code.gs:15**

Would anyone be able to assist. It looks like this row is what's causing the issue, but I can't figure out how to adjust it.

```
moves.forEach((r, i) => sheet.moveRows(r, lastRow - i + len - 1));
}
```

I'm really just trying to have this work correctly, but can't figure out how to update it. I also want to figure out how to update the status from "Scheduled" to "Complete" when it moves to the row under Complete but that is a secondary issue.

Comment: From your question, it seems that your showing script is [my proposed script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75343312). If my understanding is correct, I deeply apologize that my proposed script was not useful for your situation. From your question, I proposed a modified script of my proposed script for your provided Spreadsheet. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, all rows have the data validation rules. By this, the last row retrieved by `getLastRow()` returns the bottom of the sheet. I think that this is the reason for your current issue of `Error Exception: Those rows are out of bounds.`. In your situation, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the last empty row is retrieved using the sample script of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639. And, I adjust your script for your provided Spreadsheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
  Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
    const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
    return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
  };

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // or const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  const row = sheet.getRange("A4:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("Completed").findNext().getRow();
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  const moves = sheet.getRange("H4:H" + (row - 1)).getValues().reduce((ar, [f], i) => {
    if (f && f.getTime() < now) {
      const r = i + 4;
      ar.push(sheet.getRange(`A${r}:H${r}`));
    }
    return ar;
  }, []).reverse();
  const len = moves.length;
  if (len == 0) return;
  const lastRow = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(1);
  moves.forEach((r, i) => sheet.moveRows(r, lastRow + 1 - i));
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script was tested using your provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet and/or your actual Spreadsheet is different from your provided Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: This worked for me and makes perfect sense thank you so much! I didn't realize the last row script was what was causing the issue!

Comment: @Tiffani About`This worked for me and makes perfect sense thank you so much!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer